# Errors in Xcode before creating anything

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I tried to install Alamofire and I didn't know what I was doing, I think I stuffed something up when I created the Xcode project.

I get errors in the code before I even add anything to it, here is a picture to better explain it:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9P71w.png]

Any idea what this is or how to fix it?

Comment: Build your app, The error should go!

Comment: It does Ifran, but it is very annoying, plus they always come back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you set `PickerView` delegate and datasource from Interface Builder but you dint implement required method :

```
    // returns the number of 'columns' to display.
    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!) -> Int {
}

    // returns the # of rows in each component..
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
}
```

Add these two methods after `viewDidLoad` it will fix your issue.
Feel free to comment

Comment: But should it be an issue if I just created it, did nothing at all, and I am getting errors?

Comment: I don't know why it is referencing a picker view

Comment: just add these two methods once and run it

Comment: why downvote ,i faced such issue and share answer accordingly

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari I don't like down votes for helps too.. Especially when the help looks good

Comment: Exactly , but whatever we share on SO is the issue we faced earlier so on the basis of it , we do . so one should appreciate such effort rather thn downvoting

Comment: To clarify, I never downvoted it, I will upvote it now, and accept as answer, despite it not technically being the answer (in my case)